# In electron-positron annihilation, why is photon exchange dominant at energies below the Z-resonance?

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, standard-model, electroweak

[image]

In a plot of the Z resonance from e+ e- collisions, why is photon exchange dominant below the center of mass energy below the Z peak?

Answer (score 2):

Look in the link at the matrix element for the [photon diagram](https://www.southampton.ac.uk/~doug/ft1/ft115.pdf), just for e+e- to mu+mu-,the term :

[image: prop]

is the photon propagator. Photons have a mass of zero, so it does not appear in the propagator [as it should](http://www-pnp.physics.ox.ac.uk/~barra/teaching/feynman.pdf), as -m^2.

[image: Massprop]

The Z has a mass close to 90 GeV. At low energy reactions the Z propagator is small, due to the large Z  mass, and the matrix element terms of the Z contributions as long  $Q^2$ is much smaller than the mass of the Z, will be very small, and the photon propagator will dominate. As $Q^2$  passes through the resonance Z dominates, as the diagrams show.